# Do not show the "(visited on <date>)" on the references

Tags: biblatex, ieeetran, ieee-style

I'm using biblatex and I liked to not show some fields in the bibliography. I've managed to do it for the "issn", "url" and "doi" fields, but it does not work for the "urldate" field, and the "(visited on )" appears on the references. A minimal code is below. How could I hide the "(visited on )"?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{rtacft_biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}    % clears ISSN
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{url}}    % clears url
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{doi}}    % clears DOI
\begin{document}
Test \cite{xiang_novel_2010}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The reference used in the example

```
@article{xiang_novel_2010,
title = {A Novel On-Chip Active Dispersive Delay Line ({DDL}) for Analog Signal Processing},
volume = {20},
issn = {1531-1309, 1558-1764},
url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5570896/},
doi = {10.1109/LMWC.2010.2064761},
abstract = {In this letter, we report the first on-chip design of an active dispersive delay line ({DDL}) based upon the distributed amplification structure. This distributed amplifier {DDL} exhibits nanosecond delay variation in the frequency band from 11 to 15 {GHz}. An on-chip temporal imager is implemented with this active {DDL} and a linear chirp generator, realized by ramping the control voltage of a voltage controlled oscillator. The experimental data exhibits pulse stretching as well as pulse compression with this system.},
pages = {584--586},
number = {10},
journaltitle = {{IEEE} Microwave and Wireless Components Letters},
author = {Xiang, Bo and Kopa, Anthony and Apsel, Alyssa B.},
urldate = {2016-10-19},
date = {2010-10},
langid = {english},
file = {[3]A Novel On-Chip Active Dispersive Delay.pdf:/home/defrancaferr_joa/Documents/rtacft/documents/zotero/storage/IDFNSDX4/[3]A Novel On-Chip Active Dispersive Delay.pdf:application/pdf}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell `biblatex` as package option not to show the url etc.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber, url=false, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{xiang_novel_2010,
title = {A Novel On-Chip Active Dispersive Delay Line ({DDL}) for Analog Signal Processing},
volume = {20},
issn = {1531-1309, 1558-1764},
url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5570896/},
doi = {10.1109/LMWC.2010.2064761},
abstract = {In this letter, we report the first on-chip design of an active dispersive delay line ({DDL}) based upon the distributed amplification structure. This distributed amplifier {DDL} exhibits nanosecond delay variation in the frequency band from 11 to 15 {GHz}. An on-chip temporal imager is implemented with this active {DDL} and a linear chirp generator, realized by ramping the control voltage of a voltage controlled oscillator. The experimental data exhibits pulse stretching as well as pulse compression with this system.},
pages = {584--586},
number = {10},
journaltitle = {{IEEE} Microwave and Wireless Components Letters},
author = {Xiang, Bo and Kopa, Anthony and Apsel, Alyssa B.},
urldate = {2016-10-19},
date = {2010-10},
langid = {english},
file = {[3]A Novel On-Chip Active Dispersive Delay.pdf:/home/defrancaferr_joa/Documents/rtacft/documents/zotero/storage/IDFNSDX4/[3]A Novel On-Chip Active Dispersive Delay.pdf:application/pdf}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{xiang_novel_2010}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried using \usepackage[maxbibnames=2,style=chicago-authordate,backend=biber, url=false, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex} . I don't get the website but it's still showing "visited on 11/07/2017".  How can I get rid of it?

Comment: @skan Please ask a question. Long-ish answers in comments are not really comfortable.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400384/how-to-disable-biblatex-showing-visited-on-on-the-references